# Setting up 3rd party sftp server to run on port 22

Tags: rhel, sftp

I'm trying to setup CrushFTP 7 on a RHEL 6.5 machine and am having issues. If I leave everything as default I can connect using port 2222 but I need to be able to have CrushFTP respond to requests on port 22 instead of having openssh handle it. Does anyone know how to get a 3rd part sftp server to respond on port 22 instead of the default? I've looked through some random web sites and everything appears to be geared toward using openssh as the server or, if I find one related to crushftp or other 3rd party server, they just show how to install without going into details on how to get it to actually work on port 22. I found at least one site that mentions the 'subsystem' entry in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file.

edit: just tried the following to see what would happen and it appears to of made no difference. I updated `sshd_config` file with the following line:

```
Subsystem     sftp     /var/opt/CrushFTP7_PC/crushftp_init.sh
```

Comment: To make things easier, why don't use use anything besides 22 since 22 is well reserved for ssh?

Comment: As you mentioned in your question, you should be able to handle this by specifying CrushFTP as the `sftp` `subsystem` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.  (`man 8 sftp-server`).  You'll have to configure CrushFTP as the binary specified by that line.  Unfortunately in looking through their [Linux install Docs](http://www.crushftp.com/crush7wiki/Wiki.jsp?page=Linux%20Install) I don't see the support for handling only the SFTP side of the protocol over **STDOUT** as the man page specifies.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Brian. At least it seems like on the right track even though it's not currently working. I'll just keep digging to see if I can figure out how to put the pieces together.

Answer (score 1):

You have three options:

1. run alternate sftp server on a separate port
2. run sshd on a port other than 22 or not to run sshd at all - that will leave port 22 available for alternate sftp server
3. use

   ```
   Subsystem   sftp    /path/to/alternate/sftp-server
   ```

   which makes sshd handle the initial connection and handing it over to the appropriate application.

However, `/var/opt/CrushFTP7_PC/crushftp_init.sh` is unlikely what you need - as the name suggests, it is probably a script used to start a standalone service.

Comment: I tried turning off sshd earlier (probably should have put that in my original post) but all that did was make port 22 unresponsive altogether. I appreciate the response and I'll just keep digging.

Comment: Of course it made port 22 unresponsive, when you stopped the service that was listening there. That was exactly the point where you could have gone for option 2 - of course, you wouldn't have a SSH access to the machine, which usually is not the desired outcome, although in some cases it can be perfectly fine.

Comment: Maybe I should have been more clear (or maybe I'm misunderstanding you): when I turned off sshd on port 22 I turned on CrushFTP with it setup to respond to port 22 and it was still unresponsive. Am I missing what you're saying?

If I shutdown Crushftp and set it back to port 2222 with no other changes it works. If I set it back to port 22, with nothing else running on port 22, it does not work.

Comment: Well, turns out I'm an idiot. Out of desperation I just tried stopping sshd again and starting up Crushftp and it worked fine. Obviously this was a brief WTF moment. This got me wondering what was different and I couldn't think of anything so I went and took a look at my history to see if I had run any other procs or edited any other files and couldn't help but notice the lack of an 'sshd stop' entry. It appears that I thought about doing it, but never actually did it. BTW, I tried to upvote since 2 was the obvious answer but not enough rep.